# Is the Quine-Duhem thesis valid also for mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I have been studying the lack of consensus regarding e.g. the first Hilbert problem (whether a problem is solved or unsolved). It is clear for several of the problems that a fair amount of interpretation is necessary to come to a decision about whether a or not a problem is solved.

This makes me wonder whether the so called Quine-Duhem‘s thesis - that it is impossible to test a scientific hypothesis in isolation - also is valid for mathematics?

Comment: It is true that mathematical symbols carry meaning and need interpretation apart from strictly syntactic properties they might have. In fact non-trivial theorems are proved this way (by appropriately interpreting the symbols) which an automatic proof system cannot achieve (using simply syntactic information). At least in this sense the thesis holds.

Comment: @Nikos M. - If we restrict "automatic proof systems" to computable systems then Gödel's theorem shows that mathematician's general notion of arithmetical truth cannot be encapsulated by such a system. But as Carnap argued, it is possible to still have a purely syntactic notion of arithmetical truth if you allow for a non-computable inference rule, the [ω-rule](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Carnap_rule), which allows one to infer a proposition involving the universal quantifier from a countably infinite number of cases. If so, "true arithmetic" then logically follows from Peano axioms.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, interesting! I was not aware of this argument of Carnap.

Comment: [Duhem-Quine thesis (DQT)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/) is about underdetermination of scientific theories by empirical evidence. It applies to mathematics only if one subscribes to Quine's idea that mathematics is just the more "entrenched" part of science subject to empirical revision, which few do. Not every indeterminacy has to come from that, the issue with CH has more to do with undecidability of some statements in first order theories discovered by Gödel. It only relates to DQT insofar as our "evidence" did not "determine" more set theory axioms.

Comment: On further reflection it occurs to me that – as you may note - the question’s origin is not really about pure mathematics but perhaps more on what Hilbert and other mathematicians thought and might think today.